# Ruby gem for writing formulas in xls/xlsx spreadsheets?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet

Is there a Ruby gem that can write formulas to an xls/xlsx spreadsheet?  The Spreadsheet gem doesn't appear to allow this, at least not in the latest version.  Are there any gems out there that allow this or am I stuck doing it in a csv file?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem and there is a gem that will do this for you!

Check out [writeexcel](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel). It will write all those formulas you have been missing. Here is an example of how it works:

```
worksheet.write('B5', '=SIN(B4/4)')
```

Hope this helps!